# Can a Maven dependency be deleted from public use?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm using Maven in a project at work and I have several dependencies that I'm using such as Apache POI, Commons IO, Google Guava, etc. A coworker of mine however is concerned that in the future some of these dependencies could be deleted by their author and no longer be available which would break our projects build; for example if a future developer had to rebuild the project `mvn clean build` would those dependencies still be found. Is it possible for a Maven dependency to be deleted? Or once they're given to Apache or a public repository they're there for life?

Comment: once you build your project all dependencies are downloaded in the build file. So you don't have to worry about any changes as such.

Comment: You can configure a local maven repository where you can include all used dependencies and have control over them.

Answer (score 3):

Artifacts which are published on Maven Central cannot be removed. This is deliberate, without this safety net no one using these artifacts could rely on them either in future or in order to rebuild historic versions of their own software.

From [the docs](http://central.sonatype.org/articles/2014/Feb/06/can-i-change-a-component-on-central/):

> **Can I change an artifact that was published to the Central Repository?**
>
> No. Once a component has been published to the Central Repository, it cannot be altered. This rule is in place to preserve the stability and compatibility going forward.

Note: "it cannot be altered" means **no changes** to the artifact and **no removal** of the artifact.

So, as long as you are sourcing from Maven Central then this ...

> ... in the future some of these dependencies could be deleted by their author and no longer be available which would break our projects build

... is not a concern.

In addition, even if Maven Central no longer existed (and nothing sprang up to replace it) the artifacts you mentioned (Apache POI, Commons IO, Google Guava) are all open source so you could build the artifacts yourself and serve them up to yourself.